# Using Template Haskell to add libraries with which to link

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi, template-haskell

I'm currently hacking my way through trying to make quasiquotes for writing Rust code inline in Haskell. I think I have the code generation work done (including things like marshaling Haskell types to and from generated Rust ones). I now have the problem of figuring out how to do all the compilation and linking from within Template Haskell. The pipeline is as follows:

1. The quasiquote gets parsed
2. Source code is generated for

   - a corresponding Rust function
   - Haskell FFI imports
   - the Haskell call to the imported function
3. The Rust code gets compiled into a static library (like `rustc --crate-type=staticlib  qq_function.rs -o qq_function.a`)
4. The Haskell code gets compiled and linked against `qq_function.a` (and a handful of other libraries like `m`, `c`, etc.)

**My issue is getting steps 3 and 4 to happen entirely within `TemplateHaskell`**. Here is as far as I've gotten:

- [`runIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.12.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:runIO) can write out the Rust source files that I've generated
- [`addDependentFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.12.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:addDependentFile) informs GHC that the generated Rust file is a dependency
- [`addForeignFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.12.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:addForeignFile) regrettably does *not* work for automatically managing the compilation since Rust is not a supported language (this is the approach `inline-c` takes since C *is* a supported language)
- [`runIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.12.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:runIO) could be used to generate the static Rust library (and delete the Rust source file afterwards) by calling out to `rustc`.

What is still very much not clear to me is

1. how I can use Template Haskell to add libraries against which to link and
2. how I can use Template Haskell to clean up these generated libraries afterwards?

## EDIT

I've filed a [GHC feature request](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14298#ticket) related to this.

Comment: this sounds a lot like the work mathieu boespflug and his colleagues at tweag.io did with inline-r (and sister projects) have you had a look at their work how they solved these problems?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Yes. Their work especially with `inline-java` has been really cool. That said, my (very vague and likely incorrect) understanding is that `inline-r` just calls out to the R interpreter and `inline-java` calls out to the JVM (albeit with some super cool tricks with byte code). The point remains that neither of these really statically links anything. That's not a performance price I should have to pay here. In any case, it is a different problem.

Comment: I have to admit my understanding of th/ffi is quite limited - so I can't help with your problem but - https://github.com/fpco?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=inline - has something about c/cpp, which **is** not interpreted (or at least i think so) - maybe it helps

Comment: @epsilonhalbe I mention `inline-c` in my question. :) C, CPP, and ObjectiveC have a blessed special status in TH via [`addForeignFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.12.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:addForeignFile). Rust (obviously) doesn't have that. I wonder if patching GHC to support adding compiled object files as well would be worth it.

Comment: shame on me - shame on my cow ;-)

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Not at all. I couldn't believe it when I realized this. It seems pretty inelegant. Also [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.12.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#t:ForeignSrcLang) are the supported languages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155570/discussion-between-epsilonhalbe-and-alec).